# What role does MVVM play in ASP.NET MVC 4 web applications?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, web-applications, mvvm, knockout.js

While I'm reading the book "ASP.NET MVC 4" I'm wondering about MVVM. I started googling and cannot find any books about developing web applications using MVVM, so I must be missing a bit of information here.

From what I understand, MVVM is used in web applications on the client side via knockout.js and other frameworks.
If however I was to develop a Windows Phone application, I could use MVVM directly without using MVC.
Does that mean, the concept of MVVM / data binding just does not apply to client-server web applications?

Comment: You might also wanted to look at Angular framework by google, its better then knockout

Answer (score 17, accepted):

MVVM is really sort of a subpattern. There's not really any "MVVM" web  app frameworks out there. They're all MVC and you pretty much just incorporate a view model if you want one.

With ASP.NET MVC, in particular, you just create a class, generally with a name in the form of  `[Model Name]ViewModel` or `[Model Name]VM`. That class will have only the properties from your model that you'll need to work with and anything extra that doesn't make sense to put on your actual database-backed model, like `SelectList`s, etc.

In your action, you just pass an instance of this view model to your view instead of your model:

```
return View(viewModelInstance);
```

And, of course, make sure your view accepts that:

```
@model Namespace.To.MyViewModel
```

The only slightly complicated part is wiring the view model to the model (i.e., getting data to/from the view model/model. You can do this manually by explicitly mapping the properties, or you can use something like [AutoMapper](http://automapper.org/).

Comment: Angular by google , knockout are MVVM frameworks which are built on jquery

Comment: Sorry, I should have been more specific. I meant web application frameworks. I'm not aware of any pure MVVM web stacks.

Answer (score 7):

MVVM is the standard design pattern for WPF/Silverlight development, and should not be confused with MVC for ASP.Net development.

The two may sound similar and share some common parts, but they are two different design patterns.

From what I learned about knockout.js, it was designed to create "data bindings" similar to what you would use in WPF/Silverlight development, which is why the MVVM design pattern applies there.

To quote from another [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11401275/302677) of mine regarding the differences between MVVM and MVC

> In **MVVM**, your code classes (`ViewModels`) are your application, while your `Views` are just a pretty user-friendly interface that sits on top of the application code and allows users to interact with it. This means the `ViewModels` have a huge job, because they are your application, and are responsible for everything from application flow to business logic.
>
> With **MVC**, your `Views` are your application, while your `Controller` handles application flow. Application logic is typically found in `ViewModels`, which are considered part of the M in MVC (sidenote: the M in MVC cannot be considered the same as the M in MVVM because MVC's M layer contains more functionality than MVVM's M layer). A user is given a screen (`View`), they interact with it then submit something to the `Controller`, and the `Controller` decides who does what with the data and returns a new View to the user.

Comment: I find that quote from the "another answer" very simplistic and arguably inaccurate. The "application" in that quote is implying business logic and if so you do not put business logic in VM in MVVM nor M in MVC.  The author has completely missed the whole point of V in MVVM where you generally limit the amount of code-behind so they are hardly "pretty user-friendly interface".  VM do not have a huge job.  As mentioned you limit the amount of business logic placed there

Comment: "Application logic is typically found in ViewModels, which are considered part of the M in MVC "   How is that so ? The M in MVC contains only the models (usually POCO classes) , I think the application logic is in the controller? correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: @zeppelin Perhaps things have changed, but a few years ago when I was going through MVC tutorials and looking at MVC templates in VS, I seem to recall classes called "ViewModel" in the Models folder. They weren't actually ViewModels in the same sense as MVVM ViewModels though. Both objects provided data for the View, but MVVM ViewModels frequently do a lot of the work that is found in a MVC Controller.

Comment: The wonderful MVVC pattern has been adopted by almost every platform out there. Android development uses it and Xamarin Forms and WPF especially with the view is very powerful. You join longer have to worry about state.. like you can bind a progress bar directly to a loop counter or a shopping cart total and forget about it.

Answer (score 5):

MVC is a one-way data-binding system.

Fill your **M**odel in **C**ontroller, then pass it to **V**iew.

---

*MVVM is a two-way data-binding one.*

Fill your **M**odel, use it in **V**iew, when the **V**iew state's changes, your **M**odel update automatically.(Vice-versa)

Answer (score 3):

> Does that mean, the concept of MVVM / data binding just does not apply to client-server web applications?

No, you *can* apply the MVVM pattern to client-server web applications.

In fact Asp.Net MVC actually kind of does use this pattern - when the controller creates the view, it can pass in a "view-model". This view-model is often a POCO data object with all the data that a particular view needs, drawn from the model (database). The view uses this data to render the html page.

MVVM on wikipedia says it was introduced by Microsoft with WPF. Specifically, the view binds to properties on the view-model. The view-model then maps this to the database. By this definition then, Asp.Net does not exactly match that. Client-side frameworks like knockout.js and vue.js do support this kind of 2-way binding with view-model properties.

All these patterns are based on the fantastic MV* pattern. It was originally called the MVC design pattern. So this is the exact same pattern as Asp.Net MVC then? Actually, not quite. Controller means something completely different to start with (see [MVC on wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller)). The original MVC controller handles all user input directly not via the view. Second, the original MVC pattern was designed for a desktop app GUI and Asp.Net MVC adapted the pattern for use in a client-server web app. An ASP.Net controller is a collection of http end-points which the client-side html page can hit (eg form-post, page-navigation, ajax).

So there are a lot of M-something-V patterns and the general pattern is often called the MVC design pattern.

There's one more important wrinkle: client-side vs server-side. We've introduced rich client-side javascript frameworks and the fantastic MV* pattern is great here too. So now we could have something like: client-side View-Model-ServerHTTPEndPoints and server-side ServerHTTPEndPoints-ServerModel. The server-endpoints refers to Asp.Net controllers or the equivalent in whatever web framework or programming language you are using. From the server-side point of view, the entire client-side html is the view. The client-side model talks to the server ajax api (http endpoints) to sync data or trigger advanced actions. The ServerModel is normally a database. In knockout/vue, instead of client-side "Model", it would be ViewModel. If you use react/vue with redux/flux then the client-side would be View-ViewModel-Model-ServerHTTPEndPoints where the Model would be the redux/flux Stores. Also, often on the server-side, a service is introduced: ServerHTTPEndPoints-Service-Model. This way unit tests can hit the service directly rather than firing up the entire web server and making HTTP connections.

Answer (score 0):

I have used MVVM in desktop applications and I have a property in my viewmodels named Model where I store a business object as the model. My views have a property named DataContext where the viewmodels are stored before the views are loaded. A view bind its controls to the business object using the path DataContext.Model.BusObjPropertyName. I have a UserInteractionService that register from the start the relationships between views and viewmodels. When a viewmodel needs to show another viewmodel, it calls the method ShowView in the UserInteractionService and pass the viewmodel as parameter. Then the service instantiate the view corresponding to the viewmodel received, set its DataContext property with the viewmodel and show it.

If it is possible to do the bindings to a path like that above in Asp, all this model can be reused either in desktop as in Web applications.